# Using php fopen for user widget creation?

Tags: php, mysql, widget, membership

Scenario: I have a bookmark widget that saves images online. You drag an image to a bookmarklet, which submits to widget.php. I want to create a user system and provide each user with their own widget.

I understand (I'm not a developer) that I can use fopen to create new files, but I'm looking for a deeper understanding of this.

I think what I'm looking to understand is, when a user signs up, I need to activate fopen to create 1) a bookmarklet for them and 2) their own version of widget.php?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You don't need a whole new `widget.php` file, you just need to have it accept an argument of a unique ID for the user, and hardcode the user's unique id into their bookmarklet. That is the simple, although in many ways flawed, approach.

Comment: You could have `widget.php` redirect to a login page on first use, then set a cookie (or create a long running session) to keep the user logged in. The cookie will be sent each time without the need to "hard code" a unique id into their bookmarklet

Comment: (function () {
 var jsScript = document.createElement('script');

 jsScript.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
 jsScript.setAttribute('src', '/widget.php?url='image');

 document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jsScript);
})();

Comment: Dave, so you think that something like 

/widget.php?userid=12345&url='image'

would be more simple way to do it, but a flawed way as well?

Answer (score 0):

Your question drops down to: how to program a server side user system, or, more broadly, "how to program php", that is not something one can explain in a Stackoverlow answer.

Internet is full of very good resources to learn how to program and PHP is very wide spread programming language (and fairly easy to start with, as well).

If you're looking after `fopen`, by the way, you're doing it wrong. You need to store user information somewhere (a plain text file like the one created by fopen is an option, but you want to have a database), get what user is submitting the bookmark (is it logged already? if not, provide a login form) and of course everything related to user management: account creation, deletion, password recovery, login and logout...

Comment: Got it. I have a general understanding of user systems and connecting php to mysql for this purpose. Based on your response a)sorry! I'll use StackOverflow in a more appropriate fashion moving forward and b) I can use php to create new users and provide them with their own profiles, but it I also need to provide them with their own bookmarklet, why would fopen not be the way to go? (Or is the question still too broad?)